# Increasing size of OUT BIND in node oracle. NJS-016: buffer is too small for OUT binds at Error (native)

Tags: node.js, oracle, sails.js, node-oracledb

I am using sails-oracle-db adapter to connect my sails application to oracle.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-oracle-db

sails-oracle-db internally uses 
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb

I have defined by model as

```
tableName: 'DATAPASS',
schema: true,
connection: 'oracle',
attributes: {
    id: {
        type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: 'float',
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    startDate: {
        type: 'date',

    },
    endDate: {
        type: 'date',

    },
    tags: {
        type: 'json'
    },
    status: {
        type: 'integer'
    },
    assets: {
        type: 'json',
    }
```

In the oracle database i have a table named datapass which has a column named asset ( varchar2 and its size is 4000 Bytes )

When i am inserting data into this column as say it has a value of

```
var asset =[{"name":"Metered Data","identifier":"meteredData","formName":"dataAsset","multiple":false,"formFields":{"label":"28GB","value":28,"unit":"GB"}}]
```

then every thing is working fine

but when add one more entry to the asset array and the size of data is less than 4000Bytes

```
[{"name":"Metered Data","identifier":"meteredData","formName":"dataAsset","multiple":false,"formFields":{"label":"28GB","value":28,"unit":"GB"}},{"name":"Depletion Priority","identifier":"depletionPriority","multiple":false,"formName":"depletionPriority","formFields":{"label":"High","priority":"2"}}
```

Then it is giving me the error of

```
error:  Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
```

: NJS-016: buffer is too small for OUT binds
    at Error (native)

Answer (score 0):

I learned the inside of node-adapter with oracle and came to know about the

## DML RETURNING Bind Parameters

so when data manipulation query is fired to oracle then it returns the modified data. for example

### insert query -  returns the newly inserted row

### update query -- returnd the updated row

Now its upto the programmer wish that do we want to return all the content of the row or do we want only some specific columns of the row. This in oracle is known as DML Returning statements.

When the amount of data returned is large then the node-oracle throws an error.

`NJS-016: buffer is too small for OUT binds a`

so when we are writing our DML statements we need to take care of returning only the desired columns which we want and not all the data because it can oveflow the node buffer.

suppose we have a DML statement like

`"UPDATE mytab SET name = :name WHERE id = :id RETURNING id, name INTO :rid,:rname"`

here we are returning only two columns named as id and name only.

But if we are returning a column such as data which contains huge amount of JSON data then it will give the error

Comment: Thats not a solution, what if all columns are needed? or if the the column that contains the largest but most relevant data is needed?